# Search list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get a list of security groups a user belongs to as array of objects. I use DirectoryEntry to get active directory properties and one of the properties is "memberOf" (de.properties["memberOf"].value). The return values is an "array of objects". Each element of this array of objects look something like:

```
"CN=SITE_MAINTENANCE,OU=CMS,OU=SD,OU=ESM,OU=Engineering Systems,DC=usa,DC=abc,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

I can loop through the elements, cast each element as "string" and search this way. I just thought there might be an easier way that does not require looping.
I need to be able to find the one(s) with OU=CMS in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. How is that string you posted related to the array of objects? Is it a list of strings that look like the above?

Comment: What DirectoryEntry returns for "memberOf" is "object[]". But when I examine it, each entry (object) in the array looks like the string I posted. Because it is object[], I cannot do any string function. As I said, I can loop through each element, cast each one as string and search that way but thought there miight be a more intelligent way.

Comment: Well, if it returns an `object[]` there's not much else you can do. I guess the API isn't very intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array and then use indexOf or Regexp search for the string "OU=CMS".  If it exists in the string, then you've "found the one(s) with OU=CMS in it."

You can do anything like throwing the items into a new list or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Where(a=>a.ToString().Contains("OU=CMS")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like follows

```
string listString="CN=SITE_MAINTENANCE,OU=CMS,OU=SD,OU=ESM,"+
                     "OU=Engineering Systems,DC=usa,DC=abc,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Using linq:

```
listString.Split(',').Contains("OU=CMS")
```

W/o linq:

```
Array.IndexOf(listString.Split(','), "OU=CMS") >= 0
```

Comment: What I have is an array of objects, each element of the array is the string I included as an example. I get this from DirectoryEntry (de.properties["memberOf"]) which returns an array of objecs.

Comment: can you edit you question with these details. Means what is inside your array of objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can search required value by foreach loop

Comment: A bit more detail would help the OP